# Error code (200,-82), MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK in Android

Tags: android, android-videoview

Below code is for play remote video of mine:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(URLPath);

vv.setVideoURI(uri);
vv.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
//play next one
}
});

vv.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
return false;
}
});
```

It works for most of my devices.
But it does not works in some devices(Such as Samsung Galaxy S2).
I get the error code `Error (200,-82)`.
I found it is `MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK`.
What did it mean?
And how to avoid it?

Comment: What is the media file? .mp4, .3gp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) as doc says :

> The video is streamed and its container is not valid for progressive
>   playback i.e the video's index (e.g moov atom) is not at the start of
>   the file.

The MediaPlayer often change to error state when playing video,and then prompt "can't play this video" dialog, so you have to handle these error via remembering the played time and replaying video after reset MediaPlayer engine.

You can implement  `OnErrorListener` in your code for handling this type of errors as:

```
private MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener mOnErrorListener = new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

 public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

   switch (what) {

    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
         Toast.makeText(PlayerActivity.this, "MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                         
         return true;
    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
        Toast.makeText(PlayerActivity.this,
                                            "MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;
     case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
         Toast.makeText(PlayerActivity.this, "MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;
        }

         setProgressContainer(true, getString(R.string.msg_handle_error));
        int position=mVideoView.getCurrentPosition();
        if(position>0){
                   mCurPosition=position;
        }
         mVideoView.setVideoPath(mCurrentMediaUrl,position);

         return true;
         }

};
```

Comment: Another problem, this error is cause by different devices or by different Android versions?

Comment: This is a good way to perform an action and log when this error is received, however, it doesn't not catch the error before the dialog appears. Not sure if you can do that.